# How could I extract a substring from large text using a macro in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, string, macros, notepad++

The text is newline delimited.

E.g.

> ```
> Doe, Jon <djon@asasd.com> 
> Pat, Bob <pbob@askdja.com>
> ```

I'd like to extract only the text between `<` and `>`, and add a `;` (and a newline) between each substring, such that the end result looks like this:

```
djon@asasd.com;
pbob@askdja.com;
```

Is this possible with Notepad++? Are there other alternatives with which I could get this done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `Search & Replace` with enabled `Regex` checkbox.

Search for:

```
.*?<(.*?)>
```

Replace for:

```
\1;
```

Comment: I do not know if names are correct because I do not use english version of Notepad++, but idea is the same. :-)